# Trying to build like system with Laravel and Fractal

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm having troubles building my forum API. Basiclly, I'm trying to make the posts "likeable" by users. I'm using many-to-many polymorph relationship.
Using laravel-fractal by spatie.

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "uus teema",
        "slug": "uus-teema",
        "body": "teema sisu",
        "diffForHumans": "5 minutes ago",
        "user": {
            "data": {
                "username": "ventt",
                "avatar": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f89167803d475a4c6309cb888273d9bb?s=35&d=mm"
             }
        },
        "posts": {
             "data": [
             {
                 "id": 1,
                 "body": "joujoujouuuuu wadap boys",
                 "diffForHumans": "5 minutes ago"
             }
          ]
      },
     "likes": {
         "data": []
     }
 }
}
```

The thing is, I would to show the "likes" array inside the post array, not below it.

This method will return the array I copied here earlier.

```
public function show(Topic $topic) {
    return fractal()
            ->item($topic)
            ->includeUser()
            ->includePosts()
            ->includeLikes()
            ->transformWith(new TopicTransformer)
            ->toArray();
}
```

This is includes the likes.

```
public function includeLikes(Topic $topic) {
    return $this->collection($topic->likes, new LikeTransformer);
}
```

How should lI continue?

Comment: From what you are describing, shouldn't ```likes``` be related to posts?

Comment: If likes are supposed to be children of posts, then your client should be able to request nested includes. I have never used spatie's library yet but I have used Dingo before, which also uses fractal and I can do nested includes using dot notation (eg. "endpoint?include=posts.likes")